# Format excel file with colors pd.ExcelWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe df

```
df
Out[15]: 
           Subject ID  
StartDate                                                                    
2017-11-06        ID1  
2017-11-07        ID1
2017-11-08        ID2  
2017-11-10        ID3
```

and I save it in an excel file

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(folders_path,'summary.xls'))
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

However I would like to format the color of the rows according to the `Subject ID` , i.e. I would like a different colour for each ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the 'xlsxwriter' engine and define your formats.

Below is a snippet of what is possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

data = [['2017-11-06', 'ID1'],
        ['2017-11-07', 'ID1'],
        ['2017-11-08', 'ID2'],
        ['2017-11-10', 'ID3']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['StartDate', 'Subject ID'])
print(df)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/spomared/tmp/summary.xls', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

my_formats = {'"ID1"': '#FF0000',
              '"ID2"': '#00FF00',
              '"ID3"': '#0000FF'}

for val, color in my_formats.items():
    fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': color})
    worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B5', {'type': 'cell',
                                           'criteria': '=',
                                           'value': val,
                                           'format': fmt})

writer.save()
```

Here is the output Excel file:

[image]

You can find some references of conditional formatting on http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to color all the rows (background).. not only the "IDs"...is that possible?

Comment: Of course: just change the `font_color` keyword by `bg_color` in workbook.add_format. Consider looking at the given xlsxwriter link: it shows lots of use cases.

Comment: See the format help page to have a list of available options: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html