# keep row highlighting after writing pandas dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

i have the following code where in I am trying to apply some highlighting to my dataframe then writing it to an excel sheet. However i am unable to see the highlighting in the excel sheet.

```
df_merged_styled_data = df_merged_data.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: green' if x['Snap TV (Orc)'] == x['Snap TV (VC)'] else 'background: red' for i in x], axis=1)

with pd.ExcelWriter('US_HK_PNL_data.xlsx', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df_merged_styled_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data Discrepancies', index=False)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580991/format-excel-file-with-colors-pd-excelwriter) helps?